# Java private messaging

Tags: java, java-io

i am having a problem with private messages in java. I ask the user for a "name" when they launch the Client, and it is a variable in ChatClient.java file. I have made it "public", but when i try to call it in the ChatServer.java it says "cannot find symbol". Any help with that? Also in this snippet i am searching for the right "name" from users, should there be anything defiying the "i" name? (like i.name or some sort of connection between the current client and their name).

ChatServer problematic part

```
public void sendPrivate(String message) throws Exception {
    Iterator<Socket> i = clients.iterator();

    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(message.substring(7,message.length()),", ");

     String realMessage = st.nextToken();                   
     String to = st.nextToken();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        Socket socket = (Socket) i.next();
        try {
            if (name.equals(to)){
                DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); // create output stream for sending messages to the client
                out.writeUTF(realMessage); // send message to the client
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("[system] could not send message to a client");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
    }
}
```

ChatClient part where the user inputs their "name"

```
public class ChatClient extends Thread
{
    public String name;
    protected int serverPort = 8888;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new ChatClient();
}

public ChatClient() throws Exception {
    Socket socket = null;
    DataInputStream in = null;
    DataOutputStream out = null;

    //whitelistaned
    String[] whitelist = {"Bob", "Frank", "Goliath", "Zealot", "Bruce Wayne"};
    int aliUstrezas = 0;

    //common courtesy
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Would you fancy in telling me your name, sir ?");
    System.out.println("Current whitelist: {'Bob', 'Frank', 'Goliath', 'Zealot', 'Bruce Wayne'} ");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    name = sc.nextLine();
```

Comment: can you provide the exact error message please, add it into the question itself

Answer (score 2):

`ChatServer` does not instantiate a object of type `ChatClient`, so it does not matter if `name` is public or not, it can not magically read variables from any arbitrary object.

Comment: Furthermore, it wouldn't really make sense for ChatServer to have a reference to a ChatClient object, since they're conceptually expected to be on different hosts.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Furthermore, they are probably already running in different JVMs - Yay GW

Comment: But how do i get in in there than?

Comment: @Z3br3 Send it through the socket, like the rest of your data.